# Do one need to have a software knowledge before hand to be a graphics designer?

Tags: education

i am 17 year old , pursuing high school .So my question is that do we need an ip subject in class 12 to pursue in this field cause i dont have one..I really do love to draw thing specially anime and want to be in this field ..i dont have any idea about it..anyone can explain me about this

Answer (score 1):

In theory: No, graphic designers have existed and worked succesfully when software was only a theoretical idea of the propellerheads.

In practice: Software is extremely useful tool to transform your idea to a visible work and deliver it. In addition it's a media where you can apply your creativity. It offers plenty of possiblities which are impractical with older methods.

So, in practice the answer is yes. Without software you cannot master rich enough variety of styles and areas with technical perfectness and speed expected today.

NOTES:

1) Drawing and painting physically haven't vanished. The more you are able to paint or draw onto paper or canvas, the more software gives to you new possiblities.

2) Software is no substitute for talent and passion. A person who can use software only technically cannot fool others very long claiming he's an artist.

Comment: +1  finding work with only traditional media skills can be challenging. Likewise could be said that engineers have existed before computers, however you wouldn't want to hire one that does not use computers today.